# Changing the size of a Boxy Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, boxy

I'm using the Boxy jQuery Plug-in ([Boxy Plug-In](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/boxy)) and I'm trying to change the size of the box. I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var Dialog = new Boxy("<div style='left-margin:40px;'><p><b>Event Name:</b> " + FoundType.Name + "</p><p><b>Event Type:</b> " + FoundCategory.Name + "</p><p><b>Date: </b>" + FoundType.Date.toDateString() + "</p><p><b>Comments:<br /></b>" + FoundType.Details + "</p></div>", { title: "<h><b>Detail</b></h>", modal: true, show: false });
            Dialog.resize(400, 400);
            Dialog.show();
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't call `resize` on a Boxy window *before* it's displayed. `show()` it first, then fire the `resize()`. You can also put the resize call inside the `afterShow` callback in the Boxy constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Wasn't Boxy the first attampt of Facebox modal box? http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/ you might want to try that instead.

Comment: I might try FaceBox if I don't figure it out by the end of the work day.